# How can I pass the variable in es6 promise then callback to the outside

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

The code is here:

```
function square() {
  let record = 10;
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // A mock async action using setTimeout
    setTimeout(function() { resolve(record); }, 3000);
  })
    .then(function(data) { 
      console.log('first then: ', data);
      return data * data;
    });
  return record;
 }

function submit() {
  // ...
  const result = square(); // => still 10
  // finalHandler(result);
}
submit();
```

I use setTimeout to mock one async process I have to deliver. when I call submit, the `result` pass to `finalHandler` is still the initial value 10. But what I what is the updated result, which is 100. How can I modify the `square` and the `submit` function?

Comment: Check my answer to this question, will work for you too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663680/axios-wait-on-endpoint-promise-before-returning-data/44669321?noredirect=1#comment76328527_44669321

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios wait on endpoint promise before returning data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663680/axios-wait-on-endpoint-promise-before-returning-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `square` asynchronous by returning the promise:

```
function square() {
  let record = 10;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // A mock async action using setTimeout
    setTimeout(function() { resolve(record); }, 3000);
  })
    .then(function(data) { 
      console.log('first then: ', data);
      return data * data;
    });
 }

function submit() {
  // ...
  square()
     .then(result => finalHandler(result);
}
submit();
```